# how to structure for-loop so it only executes when one round of iteration is passed?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list, and I want to return the first character that is not repeated in the list:

s = ['l','e','e','t', 'l']

so the first letter not repeated is 't'

Here is my code:

```
pointer = 0 
while pointer < len(s):
    for i in range(len(s[pointer:]))
        if s[pointer] == s[i]:
            pointer += 1

        print(s[i])
```

I recognise the issue with the code, but can't think of a solution.

So when running the iteration, we start with 'l' and compare it to all other elements in the list- the problem is when it compares to say 'e' which is the first comparison, this will cause print(s[i]) to execute.

If I move it one scope inwards, this will cause it to execute after every time pointer +=1 ; so I don't see this working either

But clearly I DO NOT want this- so where do I place "print(s[I])" so that it only executes once a round of comparison is done for an element and no duplicate is found in the list?

I can achieve this using 2 while loops quite easily, but I've come across this issue with for loops before- any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: I guess that you intend to fix a certain element, and then scan the other elements. If you scanned all of the other elements and didn't find the current element, it means that this element is unique. If I got it right, then you can just add a boolean flag before starting the second loop, this flag will indicate if the character was found.

Comment: Hi Dor- how do I do this? I mean "add a boolean flag?" - I haven't come across this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the elements, then iterate over the original list and stop after the first element that occurred only once:

```
from collections import Counter

s = ['l','e','e','t', 'l']
cnt = Counter(s)

for el in s:
    if cnt[el] == 1:
        print(el)
        break
```

Comment: Very clever- can't believe this didn't cross my mind